# Insulating Exterior Bathroom Shower Wall

Tags: bathroom, insulation

I'm renovating a bathroom in my old home and am looking for experience on how to insulate the walls around the tub, 3 of which are exterior walls. This was a mini addition many years back to make a 1/2 bath a full bath with tub. It is framed with standard 2X4's and had normal batt style insulation.

I don't expect any leaks, but there will be temperature extremes as a hot shower is taken in the cold of winter, etc. I am considering Rockwool insulation since I know it supposedly does better with any chances of moisture. This is a full renovation of the bathroom and bathtub/shower walls and will be done properly cement board backed, and tiled.  I'm just looking for ideas on how to insulate the walls.

I already used spray foam cans and sealed up all joints. Now I'm either going to use Rockwool, or, Pink Fiberglass paper insulation and then tape the seams with Tyvek tape. Some say use plastic as a vapor barrier, others say not to. I can't do a full spray foam as the area is small and I can't justify the cost since the old bathroom was doing ok, but I want to do better than it was.

I will be Redgard waterproofing the cement board.

How should I go about insulating this bathtub/shower with 3 exposed walls.

Comment: The plastic barrier will save on tape and probably do a much better job of reducing cold draft leaks.  As a vapour barrier it is probably not needed with all the other coverings.  I imagine the room is too small to think about adding 2x2s to the 2x4s for extra insulation space, depends on what is considered cold winter.

Comment: Thanks @crip659 for the reply. Yes the space is already tiny so unfortunately there is no room to build it out any further. We are in the Northeast so winters can be cold, or mild, but are always around freezing minimum in the winters.

For plastic barrier, is there a special product that breaths, or do people just use plastic sheeting of a thicker mil? I tried to find a product at the big box stores and the guys there told me just buy plastic.

Comment: Not really sure if there will be much difference between 2mil or 6mil plastic in stopping drafts, they should not breath.  6mil should stand up to more abuse when building than 2mil(less rips from oops).

Comment: Thanks @crip659, I'll go ahead and use a thicker gauge plastic.  Any ideas on Rockwool vs using pink fiberglass with paper backing? I see people suggesting both on the web, any preference?

Comment: Paper backing means lots of seams to tape for stopping drafts, besides that get the best insulation value per inch.